# Unable to burn because of medium write error

Tags: 12.04, burning

Trying to burn ubuntu 12.10 to memorex DVD+Rdl with MaxOS.  Seemed to be going well then error message popped up "unable to burn because of medium write error".  I'm hoping this is something very simple I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Memorex media tends to give a lot of errors on Macintosh computers. I highly suggest going out and purchasing some Verbatim DVD's. They are reliable and tend to work with success most of the time.